# Kotlin annotation - Require a parameter is a Constant variable from specific class

Tags: android, kotlin, annotations

I have a function `filter` here

```
fun filter(category: String) {
...
}
```

and a Class with many constant string

```
object Constants {
    val CAT_SPORT = "CAT_SPORT"
    val CAT_CAR = "CAT_CAR"
    ...
}
```

How to ensure the parameter `category` is a constant string from `Constants` (or throw warning)?

I am looking for something like `@StringRes`.

I know `Enum` may do the trick but prefer not to code refactor at this moment.

Comment: perhaps you can program that on your own, it's easy with annotation processor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using androidx.annotation you can do something like this:

```
object Constants {
    @Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
    @StringDef(CAT_SPORT, CAT_CAR)
    annotation class Category

    const val CAT_SPORT = "CAT_SPORT"
    const val CAT_CAR = "CAT_CAR"
}

fun filter(@Constants.Category category: String) {
    ...
}
```